# useState is unclear in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React. My problem is with 2 useStates I have in my program which creates tic-tac-toe field.

```
import {useState} from "react";

// Fix bug with check and setCheck

export default function FieldCell() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');
    const [check, setCheck] = useState(0);

    const handleClick = () => {
        if (check % 2 === 0) {
            setValue('X');
        }
        else {
            setValue('O');
        }
        console.log(check)
        setCheck(check + 1);
    }

    return(
        <td className="field_cell"><button onClick={handleClick}>{value}</button></td>
    );
}
```

first useState sets the value, either X or O, seconde one should decide order (first X then O). But I faced the issue that it counts clikc on each button seperately. But it should be like 'global' for all buttons and change order ( on even check - 'X', on odd - 'O' ).

I tried to call setcheck in different positions: in if statement, in else statement and in both. It obviously  didn't work.

Edited: Sorry that I havent shown all files. Here they are:

FieldCell was shown above;

FieldRow:

```
import FieldCell from "./FieldCell.jsx";

export default function FieldRow({ num_cells }) {
    let rows = [];

    for(let i=0; i<num_cells**2; i+=1) {
        rows.push(
            <FieldCell key={i} />
        )
    }

    return (
        <tr>
            {rows.slice(0, num_cells)}
        </tr>
    );

}
```

Field

```
import FieldRow from "./FieldRow.jsx";

export default function Field({ num_rows }) {
    let rows = [];

    for(let i=0; i<num_rows;i++){
        rows.push(<FieldRow key={i} num_cells={num_rows} />)
    }

    return (
        <div className="field_wrapper">
            <table className="field_table">
                <tbody>
                    {rows}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}
```

App:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import Field from "./components/Field.jsx";

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  return (
    <>
        <Field num_rows={3} />
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

UPDATE: I have tried solution which was provided below. Here are my files now:

App:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import Field from "./components/Field.jsx";
import FieldRow from "./components/FieldRow.jsx";
import FieldCell from "./components/FieldCell.jsx";

export default function App() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');
    const [check, setCheck] = useState(0);
    const handleClick = () => {
        if (check % 2 === 0) {
            setValue('X');
        }
        else {
            setValue('O');
        }
        setCheck(check + 1);
        console.log(check);
    }

    return(
        <Field num_rows={3}>
            <FieldRow>
                <FieldCell handleClick={handleClick} value={value}></FieldCell>
            </FieldRow>
        </Field>
    )
}
```

Field:

```
import FieldRow from "./FieldRow.jsx";
import {useState} from "react";

export default function Field({ num_rows }) {

    let rows = [];

    for(let i=0; i<num_rows;i++){
        rows.push(<FieldRow key={i} num_cells={num_rows} />)
    }

    return (
        <div className="field_wrapper">
            <table className="field_table">
                <tbody>
                    {rows}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}
```

FieldRow:

```
import FieldCell from "./FieldCell.jsx";

export default function FieldRow({ num_cells }) {
    let rows = [];

    for(let i=0; i<num_cells**2; i+=1) {
        rows.push(
            <FieldCell key={i} />
        )
    }

    return (
        <tr>
            {rows.slice(0, num_cells)}
        </tr>
    );

}
```

FieldCell:

```
export default function FieldCell({ handleClick, value }) {
    return(
        <td className="field_cell"><button onClick={handleClick}>{value}</button></td>
    );
}
```

But now it doesn't even respond on clicking and doesn't put any value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and it should work now

**App.jsx**

```js
import Field from "./components/Field.jsx";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [check, setCheck] = useState(0);

  return <Field numRows={3} check={check} handleCheck={setCheck} />;
}
```

**Field.jsx**

```js
import FieldRow from "./FieldRow.jsx";

export default function Field({ numRows, handleCheck, check }) {
  let rows = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    rows.push(i);
  }

  return (
    <div className="field_wrapper">
      <table className="field_table">
        <tbody>
          {rows.map((index) => (
            <FieldRow
              key={index}
              numCells={numRows}
              handleCheck={handleCheck}
              check={check}
            />
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**FieldRow.jsx**

```js
import FieldCell from "./FieldCell.jsx";

export default function FieldRow({ numCells, handleCheck, check }) {
  let rows = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < numCells ** 2; i += 1) {
    rows.push(<FieldCell key={i} handleCheck={handleCheck} check={check} />);
  }

  return <tr>{rows.slice(0, numCells)}</tr>;
}
```

**FieldCell.jsx**

```js
import { useState } from "react";

export default function FieldCell({ handleCheck, check }) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const handleClick = () => {
    if (check % 2 === 0) {
      setValue("X");
    } else {
      setValue("O");
    }
    handleCheck(check + 1);
  };
  return (
    <td className="field_cell">
      <button onClick={handleClick}>{value}</button>
    </td>
  );
}
```

Don't forget to go through the wonderful tutorial at https://www.react.dev

#react.js #javascript

Comment: Then again you don't need 2 separate states to achieve what you want to achieve. You can simply refactor your states into a single object-based state or you can use a variable for the **check** and leave **value** as state. Make sure you check out the link I recommended

Comment: thank you for solution but actually I have Fieldrow.jsx file in which I create <tr>s as much as 'value' parsed. You have shown for 3 by 3 field case but i am trying to make user to be able to decide the size. Thank you again, please can you clarify a bit.

Comment: I tried it but it still didn't wotk. Maybe I made an error somewhere here, but please, check the update.

Comment: You're welcome, keep enjoying React ✌️

Answer (score 1):

you need to make sure that you're using the updated value of check when you decide whether to set 'X' or 'O', becasue the updates might not be immediately reflected in the multiple calls to handleClick

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
export default function FieldCell() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [check, setCheck] = useState(0);

  const handleClick = () => {
    const newCheck = check + 1; // Increment before using the updated value

    if (newCheck % 2 === 0) {
      setValue("X");
    } else {
      setValue("O");
    }

    setCheck(newCheck);
  };

  return (
    <td className="field_cell">
      <button onClick={handleClick}>{value}</button>
    </td>
  );
}
```

Comment: But It worked so now I have only 'O' but no 'X'.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update value and check on the click of the `button` as:

Simplest way will be to reset its state, since there gonna be two player and at any time there gonna be a single player whose turn will be. So based on that you can set its state.

```
const handleClick = () => {
  const isEven = !check;
  setValue(isEven ? "X" : "O");
  setCheck(isEven ? 1 : 0);
};
```

Comment: Sorry but i didn't really get it. If you meant that I have to change turn for two players, I am using check for that reason. But I am sure you have meant smth else, so please, clarify a bit.